# Не открываются файлы MS Office из VBS-скрипта планировщика задач

Tags: windows, excel, ms-word, vbscript

Существует VBS-скрипт, который открывает документы Word и Excel.

```
  Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Затем запускает макросы из них.

```
  Set wdDoc =  wdApp.Documents.Open(macros_file) 
  Set xlDoc =  xlApp.Workbooks.Open(macros_file, 0, True)
```

При работе в пользовательском режиме скрипт работает без проблем в Windows 10.
Суть проблемы в том, что в созданной задаче по запуску скрипта (используется *Планировщик заданий*) , файлы **не открываются**.
Т.е. объекты **wdDoc** и **xlDoc** - пустые.

Проблема типична для **скрытой задачи**, запускаемой от имени пользователя вне зависимости от регистрации пользователя.

Как решить проблему?

P.S. Изменение настройки выполнения задачи не влияет на ошибку: "Windows 10"; "Windows 7.."; "Windows Vista..."

Answer (score 0):

Решение "нагуглил" в форме подсказки на одном из [форумов](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/ac2549f5-fc1e-494d-9015-70cb31d3aeb2/opening-excel-workbook-fails-when-run-from-scheduled-task-on-windows-server-2008-rw).
Пользователь посоветовал создать каталог **Desktop** в папке **C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile**
Это помогло, скрипт заработал.

Однако при переносе скрипта на рабочую машину этот трюк не сработал. Проблема осталась.
Кстати скрипт на всякий случай запускался для 32-разрядного окружения, а именно: **C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe**

Тогда был создан каталог **Desktop** в папке **C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile** и проблема была окончательно решена.

P.S.Не понятно в чем была разница конфигурации на двух машинах из одного дистрибутива 64-разрядной Win10Pro. При том что на предыдущей машине не было соответствующего каталога. Поэтому на всякий случай оставлю тут решение как памятку.

Comment: Ужс... а всего-то и надо было что указывать не голозадое имя файла, а полное - с диском и путём. Ибо текущий каталог в пользовательском режиме и в режиме запуска планировщиком - немножко не одно и то же... ну и убедиться, что прав на доступ к файлу - хватит у учётки, от которой выполняется задание.

Comment: Выставление полного имени пути в параметрах запуска скрипта нисколько не решало проблему. А права на доступ к файлам скрипта - однозначно есть у ВСЕХ пользователей системы. А вот то, что профилю пользователя services, от которого стартовала задача планировщика, понадобится наличие каталога Desktop - вещь совершенно **не очевидная**

Comment: *профилю пользователя services, от которого стартовала задача планировщика, понадобится наличие каталога Desktop* Обычным VBS-скриптам, стартующим из планировщика, ни десктоп, ни другой каталог вообще не упёрлись - так что это следствие особенностей отдельно взятого скрипта, не иначе. Я уж не говорю о такой простой вещи, что для попадания в `C:\Windows\System32\config\` надо быть админом, да и в этом случае разрешение на доступ в каталог надо запрашивать отдельно.

Comment: Да и изначально - создавать заведомо интерактивный объект в условиях, когда ему тупо не с чем интерактивить... Обычно такие задания всё же запускают от имени определённой учётной записи - даже если надо запускать при старте рабочей станции. Ну и - надо было хотя бы посмотреть, какая именно ошибка возникает при попытке создания объекта.

Comment: Я об этом и толкую - это задание запускалось от имени конкретного пользователя домена. Однако процессы отображались (во время выполнения в списке процессов) от имени сервисной учетной записи планировщика, как это не выглядело бы странно. Пользователь домена - естественно, находился в списка локальной группы пользователей компьютера. Т.е. права на доступ к файлам и на доступ к запуску процессов у пользователя есть.

Comment: К предыдущему комментарию, процесс все-таки порождался от доменного пользователя. Он (процесс) относился к сеансу пользователя сервиса планировщика.